# Live event on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I added DOM elements with `class="divhide"` with `$.getJSON`.

Now I have many div with `class="title"` and I add event, but this doesn't work:

```
$('.title').on("click",'div.divhide' , function () {
    var description = $(this).find('.divhide')
    description.slideToggle();
})
```

I also add `class="title"` in getJSON.

Comment: Either `.title` does not exist in the DOM when you try and attach the event, or there is not a nested `.divhide` element within the one that raised the event. My money's on the latter. We'd need to see your HTML to be sure.

Comment: did you also add the .title elements in said getJSON? sounds like it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide more context, which items are static and which are dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding `.title` elements via `getJSON` after the click handler is added, the handler will not be attached to the new elements.

Elements must exist when you apply handlers. That's why we use delegation. In other words, attach the handler to a parent element that will always exist, or at minimum exists when the handler code is applied:

```
$('body').on("click",'div.divhide' , function () {
    var description = $(this).find('.divhide')
    description.slideToggle();
})
```

This is an extreme example (and probably not wise), as you may not want to filter all of your clicks on the page. However, as body will always exist, it will handle each click and filter to see if the initial click was on `div.divhide`.

Instead of `body`, find a parent of the `.title` divs that will not be modified by your `getJSON` calls and exists when you apply the handler.